# 2nd loop inside the script or asking to enter value

Tags: bash, loops, input

I have written a code but I am having a problem to make the double loop in my bash script. This script should read all the files 1 by 1 in the given directory to upload but the value of "XYZ" changes for each file. Is there a way for me to make the code ask me to enter the "XYZ" every time it reads a new file to upload? (if possible with the name of the file read) like "please enter the XYZ value of 'read file's name'" I could not think of any possible ways of doing so. I also have the XYZ values listed in a file in a different directory so maybe can it be called like the do loop I did for the path? I might actually need to use both cases as well...

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/user/downloads/files/
for f in $FILES
do
curl -F pitch=9 -F Name='astn' -F 
"path=@/home/user/downloads/files;$f" -F "pass 1234" -F "XYZ= 1.2" -
F time=30 -F outputFormat=json 
"http://blablabla.com"
done
```

Comment: Look into using the read command

Comment: I am able to ask it for a single case but I could not make it read all to ask 1 by 1 actually...

Comment: So where is read in the code?

Comment: that's why i did not put it to the code because it only asks one time not for the whole case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following once.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/user/downloads/files/
for f in $FILES
do
echo "Please enter the name variable value here:"
read Name
curl -F pitch=9 -F "$Name" -F 
"path=@/home/user/downloads/files;$f" -F "pass 1234" -F "XYZ= 1.2" -
F time=30 -F outputFormat=json 
"http://blablabla.com"
done
```

I have entered a read command inside loop so each time it will prompt user for a value, since you haven't provided more details about your requirement so I haven't tested it completely.

Comment: This is exactly what I want but this gives an error : Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here

Comment: change "$Name" to $Name once in code and let me know how it goes then.

Comment: The error is still exactly the same. I know the code is working when I enter the -F "Name=Jack" inside the code and run it but like this it does not work so the problem is the echo-read loop somehow :/

Answer (score 1):

The problem was actually the argument. By changing it to:

```
-F Name="$Name"
```

solved the problem. Trying to link the argument such as only $Name or "$Name" causes a bad reception.

Comment: Not sure why you have removed correct answer from mine answer, you could EDIT my answer with this one and still select it as correct one.

Comment: OH sorry did know about that. Fixed it back!

Comment: Np, you could edit my answer if you want to add more information in it too, cheers.